# ReactJs: Jest failed to parse a file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm using react with typecript and after adding swiper dependecy my tests start to fail.

[image]

These are my configuration:

jest.config.js:

import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

```
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!swiper|ssr-window|dom7/)'],
};
export default config;
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow'],
  plugins: [
    'babel-plugin-styled-components',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },
};
```

package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "swiper/react": "swiper/react/swiper-react.js",
      "swiper/css": "swiper/swiper.min.css"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.css$": "jest-transform-css"
    }
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": "node_modules/(?!(swiper|ssr-window|dom7)/)",
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @JRichardsz nope still havent solved it yet

Comment: Could you replicate the issue with a hello world sample? You can find a lot on GitHub, then download, add jest and try again. Share the new repository to help you

Answer (score 0):

After doing lots of research and applying them, the only solution i found was to downgrade to v6

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same issue with swiper and these lines in jest.config.js solved it:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!swiper|ssr-window|dom7)'],
moduleNameMapper: {
    'swiper/react': ['<rootDir>/node_modules/swiper/react/swiper-react.js'],
},
```